# Как узнать расширение файла при его загрузке по ссылке?

Tags: php, curl

Использую код, указанный ниже, для загрузки файлов. Всё работает отлично, но в итоговом варианте,  расширение у загружаемого файла может быть разное, можно ли как-то узнать расширение файла при его загрузке?

код:

```
$url = 'http://mysite.ru/myfile';       
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents("TendersDocs/1.xlsx", $data);
```

Comment: вы хотите получить расширение используя php скрипт и массив $FILES?

Comment: без разницы, главное получить расширение

Comment: хотя через $_FILES мне было бы удобней

Answer (score 1):

С такой ссылкой единственное что приходит в голову это проверять mime type и присваивать по нему самое часто-используемое расширение. Но, к сожалению точно узнать расширение так не выйдет..
Если верить списку типов офисных документов от мелкомягких, путаница может быть только с устаревшими расширениями документов
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/

Answer (score 1):

Если удобно через $_FILES (для файла с именем 'file')
Способ 1.

```
$_FILES['file']['type']
```

Способ 2.

```
mime_content_type($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])
```

Способ 3.

```
pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
```

Способ 4.

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // возвращает mime-тип
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: вы не поняли сути вопроса

Answer (score -1):

Например для файла с именем $filename

```
   $arr=explode('.',$_FILES[$filename][name]);
   $rashireniye=$arr[count($arr)-1];
```

Comment: что здесь будет выступать в роли filename?

Comment: путь к закачиваемому файлу вместе с названием. Например, /local/images/img.jgp